# find a transaction

Tags: transactions, verification, lost-transactions

I made a bitcoin transaction and while I was typing in my email the window closed, so I didn't get my receipt. I have the phone number I used, one time password, wallet address, and the machine location. Can I find this transaction because it has not went thru.

Comment: From the sounds of it, you were using some sort of Bitcoin ATM. You'll need to contact the ATM business' customer service for help, nobody here will be able to provide you any assistance in the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you used some service to purchase and withdraw bitcoins.

If you sent the bitcoins to yourself, the wallet that you used to generate the receiver address should notify you of the incoming transaction.

If you sent to another network participant, and the "wallet address" you mention is the recipients invoice address, you can use a block explorer (e.g. [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com)) to find the transaction by searching for the wallet address.

If the transaction does not show up on a blockexplorer, there are essentially two possibilities:

- the purchase was interrupted before it was finalized:
  verify that this is the case and try again later once you are sure
- the service has not yet delivered their side of the deal:
  the service may have a technical issue, or more likely, the service is actually a scam

Either way, you should look to contact the customer service as we don't have insight into their internal processes. Under no circumstances, give them any more money if they don't deliver on their first service offering.